# Angular BehaviorSubject and error exception

Tags: angular, error-handling, service, behavior

I have a service that makes an http call to save to the database and sometimes retrieve a custom exception. My problem is how to recover the exception for reporting to the form via the behavior subject

My Service :

```
  data$ = new BehaviorSubject({
    users: [],
    create: false
  });
  

  constructor(  }​​

  dispatch(action: Action): Observable<true | { error: string; }> {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionTypes.USER_CREATE:
        this.createUser(action.payload);
        return of(true);
      default:
        return of(true);
    }
  }

  private createUser(user: User){
    this.http.post({body : user}).pipe(
      map((result) => result),
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err.error?.title === 'Custom' && err.status === 400) {
          ////Get and return exception
          return throwError(err);
        } else {
          return throwError(err);
        }
      })
    )
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data$.next({...this.data$.value, create: true});

    });
  }
```

My comp :

```
this.userService.dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.USER_CREATE payload: user });
this.userService.data$.subscribe((data) =>{
  console.log(data);;
  this.router.navigate(['/users/user/list']);
});
```

The redirection to the user list page must be done only if I have no exception

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply do something like setting your behaviorSubject shape like :

```
data$ = new BehaviorSubject({
  users: [],
  error: null,
  create: false
});
```

and set the `error` property when you catch an error :

```
private createUser(user: User){
  this.http.post({body : user}).pipe(
    map((result) => result),
    catchError((err) => {
      if (err.error?.title === 'Custom' && err.status === 400) {
        ////Get and return exception
        this.data$.next({...this.data$.value, error: 'Your error message about the is statement'}); // Maybe err.message, whatever you want
        return throwError(err);
      } else {
        // Same here with error message about your else statement
        return throwError(err);
      }
     
      // And you should think about a default error message, err.message or whatever is returned
    })
  )
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    if(response) {
      this.data$.next({...this.data$.value, create: true});
    }
  });
}
```

So you'll be able to handle the error field in your component:

```
this.userService.data$.subscribe((data) => {
  if(!data.error) {
    this.router.navigate(['/users/user/list']);
  }
  // You can also display a snackbar with the error message if you want. Adapt it with your need, maybe you only want a boolean
});
```

Comment: I have tested and this does not wait for the return of my service to go to the next page or not

Comment: @totuti You might need to add a condition in the subscribe inside `createUser()` method. Something like `if(response){ ... }` to avoid empty initial value.